# Why doesn't this Boolean Variable in or-tools work?

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I'm getting back into Google's OR tools and trying a (relatively) simple optimization. I'm using the CP SAT solver and I'm probably missing something elementary here.
I have some variables x, y and some constant c. I'd like x to be equal to 1 if y is smaller than that c, and 0 otherwise.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
model = cp_model.CpModel()
c = 50
x = model.NewBoolVar(name='x')
y = model.NewIntVar(name='y', lb=0, ub=2**10)

model.Add(x == (y < c))

model.Maximize(x+y)

status = solver.Solve(model)
```

I'm getting an error message

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'BoundedLinearExpression'
```

It seems I'm misusing OR tools syntax for my constraint here. I'm having difficulties understanding the documentation for OR tools online, and I seem to have forgotten quite a bit more about it than I thought.

Answer (score 3):

According to an example from [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling#:%7E:text=A%20channeling%20constraint%20links%20variables,variable%20to%20a%20particular%20value%22.), you're almost there.

### Build `x == (y < c)` constraint

#### Case 1: `x = true`

If `x` is `true`, then `y < c` must also be `true`. That's exactly what `OnlyEnforceIf` method is for. If an argument of `OnlyEnforceIf` is `true`, then the constraint in the `Add` method will be activated:

```
model.Add(y < c).OnlyEnforceIf(x)
```

#### Case 2: `x = false`,

As mentioned in **Case 1**, `OnlyEnforceIf` won't activate the constraint, if its argument is not evaluated to `true`. Hence, you cannot just leave case `y >= c` on its own and hope that it will be implied if `x = false`.  So, add a reverse constraint for this case as below:

```
model.Add(y >= c).OnlyEnforceIf(x.Not())
```

Since, for `x = false`, `x.Not()` will be `true`, the constraint `y >= c` will be activated and used when solving your equation.

### Full Code

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
model = cp_model.CpModel()
c = 50
x = model.NewBoolVar(name='x')
y = model.NewIntVar(name='y', lb=0, ub=2**10)

model.Add(y < c).OnlyEnforceIf(x) 
model.Add(y >= c).OnlyEnforceIf(x.Not())

model.Maximize(x+y)

status = solver.Solve(model)
```